# Why does service not work from launch file?

Tags: ros, call-service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I create a permanent service, and its client in my launch file.  All subsequent service calls fail.  I have discovered that if I kill the client and run it from the command line, then the service calls work.  The service also works if I call it directly from the command line using 'rosservice'.

I have also discovered that making the service temporary solves the issue.  I suspect that the launch file does something before the service is ready, but I don't know what.

I still want to use a permanent service for efficiency.  What can I do to fix the problem ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/381930/why-does-service-not-work-from-launch-file-?/) by [elpidiovaldez](https://answers.ros.org/users/28066/elpidiovaldez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 142 on 2021-07-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-07-07**:
Is *permanent* actually *persistent* here?

**Comment by [elpidiovaldez](https://answers.ros.org/users/28066/elpidiovaldez/) on 2021-07-12**:
Yes, I did mean 'persistent'.  I don't even remember where I got the idea they were called 'permanent' connections now.  It was something I read while investigating them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found a discussion on ROS Answers which solved the issue for me.  It is [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/281411/persistent-service-initialization/).

I simply needed to wait for the service to be created, by the launch file, before I create the service client.  The way to do it is shown below:

```
void InitializeTTS(ros::NodeHandle &n) {
  ros::service::waitForService("/tts");
  TTSclient = n.serviceClient<tts_serv::Gtts>("/tts",true);
}
```

Thanks to @appie for the advice. I looked at rosparam documentation, but I could not see how to use it to solve my issue.

---

Originally posted by [elpidiovaldez](https://answers.ros.org/users/28066/elpidiovaldez/) with karma: 142 on 2021-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0